# convert row to column, oracle sql

Tags: sql, oracle, pivot

i have data like this. and i want convert that data from row to column.

| ID | month | volume |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 202301 | 200 |
| 1234567 | 202302 | 100 |
| 1234567 | 202303 | 300 |

and i want convert like this

| ID | 202301 | 202302 | 202303 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1234567 | 200 | 100 | 300 |

please help me, and thankx be 4

Comment: **Hint** : Conditional Aggregation